# HTML/CSS Fonts: Different browsers/OSs different results

Tags: css, cross-browser, font-face

I've been working on my website and I'm using font squirrel to generate some web fonts for the website, but currently I've this differences:

**Google Chrome OSX**
[image: Google Chrome OSX]

**Google Chrome Windows**
[image: Google Chrome Windows]

**Firefox OSX**

[image: Firefox OSX]

**Firefox Windows**
[image: Firefox Windows]

**Internet Explorer**
[image: Internet Explorer]

Is there a way I can "hack" the fonts under windows so they will look more the ones under OSX? Thank you.

Comment: http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Comment: If that's the only difference you see between browsers, you're doing a lot better than most.  Besides, who on earth is ever going to notice this?  It's not like you would ever put them side by side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different systems render fonts differently. There is mostly nothing you can do about it. You can just live with it: check that on major systems (Windows, Mac, Linux, maybe some mobile systems too) the rendering is *acceptance*. They cannot and need not be the same. But if you get unacceptable results on some platform, change the font (though sometimes just changing font size, maybe even 1px larger, may help).

The issue is described e.g. at http://www.owlfolio.org/htmletc/legibility-of-embedded-web-fonts/ and in much more detail (and more technically) at http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/24/a-closer-look-at-font-rendering/

In principle, though, differences might also be caused by different typographic settings. Firefox nowadays applies kerning and common ligatures by default, other browsers don’t. But you probably won’t see such effects, for two reasons: free fonts usually don’t have ligatures or kerning pairs, and Lorem ipsum text usually does not contain character pairs where they would matter (e.g., “fi” or “To” or “Va”). Anyway, the typographic settings *can* be affected to a considerable degree using the CSS property `font-feature-settings` (or, rather, that property with various browser prefixes).

Answer (score 5):

The main difference here is not between browsers but between operating systems, this is pretty standard.

Comment: someone also told me it was something to do with pixel shapes... MACs have square pixels, pcs generally have oblong ones. Not sure if that is the reason, but most of the time you have to accept it. Also looks like IE is handling it the worst, now that's a surprise.

Comment: Moreover it strongly depends on user's settings. Eg. go through the Windows font wizard which helps you set the right smoothing/ClearType settings. See how the results vary.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no hack for this problem because there are drastic differences from browser to browser on how the actual rendered text looks.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that Windows also has ClearType. Changing its settings have an influence as well  (in Windows 7 it is a 4-step wizard).

The reason I mention this is that Windows has a native way to change font appearance and everyone will see it differently according to their ClearType settings. I don't think browsers change much but OS definitely do. Then there's monitor and resolution as well...

Don't be overly obsessed with making things look the same way on every system. You just cannot do that, whatever you try, and it's totally unnecessary.