# font looks different while coding. how to fix it?

Tags: html, css, fonts, psd

I designed a page in photo shop.

When I try to convert it to HTML the header font looks a bit different.
But I applied the same styles and font, for example size is `36pt` in Photo shop(non bold), I could get the same effect while I add BOLD when I coding in HTML.

The main problem is that, the font looks like cut letters, meaning the `" I "` looks like two dashes vertically arranged.

How to solve this?

Comment: Get used to it. You might get it look exactly like Photoshop on your computer but somebody else on another computer with a different OS or browser might get a different styling

Comment: What @jao said + try to use fonts that are a bit more popular, those should look good in any browser. Also check google web fonts: http://www.google.com/fonts

Comment: Please take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12654977/1460189

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save that "page" as an image and then put that image into an HTML file.

EDIT: I think you can just use the PRINT key on your keyboard to make it really look like on your computer - even with all the Photoshop toolbars and such! But don't forget to provide the users with the color profile and illumination profile of your monitor and an exact layout of your room, and don't forget the type of light bulb you are using, the thickness and tinting of the glass in your windows and of course the angle of the sun!

Comment: yeah.. that's a good idea.. but for responsive purpose I am trying to create the logo using codes only.

Comment: Recommending using images is an option, however it's not a very good one. Only do this if it absolutely MUST look EXACTLY the same on every browser. If you make sites purley out of images you're not gunna get far when it comes to search engine optimisation not to mention responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with converting photoshop files to a website is that Photoshop renders fonts different then browsers. In most of the cases, fonts are displayed the same as in your design, but sometimes you just can't get the fonts look exactly the same as in your photoshop file. Unfortunately, there isn't a fix for this yet.

Photoshop simply has a lot more font functionalities then browsers so you'll have to be satisfied with the simplified version in your browser.

What you can do is slice the text from the PSD as an image and include that in your HTML, but that is a very outdated method which will increase the loading time of your website.